# Spatial difference with vector functions

Tags: qgis

I have two shapefiles, one municipal boundary, one properties (3000 Geomertien).

I would like to form a spatial difference, this unfortunately does not work with the vector functions of QGIS.

Comment: Can you explain why the results of the QGIS Spatial Difference and/or Difference functions are not satisfactory?

Comment: QGIS crashes at 12%

Comment: Check the geometries of your shapes before mixing them. Also try to assign both shapes the same projection.

Comment: Geometries and projection are ok..

Comment: You might try another free GIS package - gvSIG, MapWindow, OpenJump, uDig, Grass.